# subselect columns pandas with count

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a table below

[image]

I was trying to create an additional column to count if Std_1,Std_2 and Std_3 greater than its mean value. 
for example, for ACCMGR Row, only Std_2 is greater than the average, so the new column should be 1.

Not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be a bit careful with how you specify the `axes`, but you can just use `.gt` + `.mean` + `.sum`

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'APPL': ['ACCMGR', 'ACCOUNTS', 'ADVISOR', 'AUTH', 'TEST'],
                   'Std_1': [106.875, 121.703, np.NaN, 116.8585, 1],
                   'Std_2': [130.1899, 113.4927, np.NaN, 112.4486, 4],
                   'Std_3': [107.186, 114.5418, np.NaN, 115.2699, np.NaN]})
```

#### Code

```
df = df.set_index('APPL')
df['cts'] = df.gt(df.mean(axis=1), axis=0).sum(axis=1)
df = df.reset_index()
```

#### Output:

```
       APPL     Std_1     Std_2     Std_3  cts
0    ACCMGR  106.8750  130.1899  107.1860    1
1  ACCOUNTS  121.7030  113.4927  114.5418    1
2   ADVISOR       NaN       NaN       NaN    0
3      AUTH  116.8585  112.4486  115.2699    2
4      TEST    1.0000    4.0000       NaN    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Considered dataframe

```
    quantity    price
0   6   1.45
1   3   1.85
2   2   2.25
```

apply lambda function on axis =1 , for each series of row check the column of value greater than mean and get the index of column

```
df.apply(lambda x:df.columns.get_loc(x[x>np.mean(x)].index[0]),axis=1)
```

Out:

```
quantity    price   > than mean
0   6   1.45    0
1   3   1.85    0
2   2   2.25    1
```

Comment: I  try to use the code but got the error. TypeError: ('must be str, not float', 'occurred at index 0')